# Why this import doesnt work?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to import a table in my database executing this query :

```
CREATE TABLE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ "to_import" (
  "id" int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  "reference" int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  "trackid" int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  "side_pos1" char(2) character set latin1 NOT NULL,
  "side1" varchar(255) character set latin1 NOT NULL,
  "pos1" char(2) character set latin1 NOT NULL,
  "hh1" char(2) character set latin1 NOT NULL,
  "mm1" char(2) character set latin1 NOT NULL,
  "ss1" char(2) character set latin1 NOT NULL,
  "atl1" varchar(255) character set latin1 NOT NULL,
  "side_pos2" char(2) character set latin1 NOT NULL,
  "side2" varchar(255) character set latin1 NOT NULL,
  "pos2" char(2) character set latin1 NOT NULL,
  "hh2" char(2) character set latin1 NOT NULL,
  "mm2" char(2) character set latin1 NOT NULL,
  "ss2" char(2) character set latin1 NOT NULL,
  "atl2" varchar(255) character set latin1 NOT NULL,
  "date" datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  ("id")
) AUTO_INCREMENT=1311;



#
# Dumping data for table 'to_import'
#

LOCK TABLES "to_import" WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE "to_import" DISABLE KEYS;*/
REPLACE INTO "to_import" ("id", "reference", "trackid", "side_pos1", "side1", "pos1", "hh1", "mm1", "ss1", "atl1", "side_pos2", "side2", "pos2", "hh2", "mm2", "ss2", "atl2", "date") VALUES
    ('1','0','550','0','Single Side','0','??','??','??','Noizefucker - Tons Of Bluesteel - Special Forces','0','Single Side','0','??','??','??','Noizefucker - Tons Of Bluesteel - Special Forces','2010-06-24 18:54:59');

... another replacement, like other 1200 line 


REPLACE INTO "to_import" ("id", "reference", "trackid", "side_pos1", "side1", "pos1", "hh1", "mm1", "ss1", "atl1", "side_pos2", "side2", "pos2", "hh2", "mm2", "ss2", "atl2", "date") VALUES
    ('1310','0','463','#','','20','00','41','00','Ingler - Trek','#','','20','00','41','00','Ingler - Trek','2011-04-02 00:30:02');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE "to_import" ENABLE KEYS;*/
UNLOCK TABLES;
/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;*/
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;*/
```

but I get this error :

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"to_import" (
"id" int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
"reference" i' at line 1
```

What does it mean? Tried on localhost and it works perfectly...

Comment: Tested it : Replace "to_import" To `to_import`

Comment: Still doesnt work : `near '"id" int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  "reference" int(11) unsigned N' at line 2 `

Comment: Table Name and Field Name Must before and after have ` and " is incorrect

Comment: P.S. I've exported it with HeidiSql, maybe I need to change target? at the moment I have ANSI SQL

Comment: Your exported sql not seems correct ! it's not a valid sql file

Comment: Yeah in fact I've exported it as ANSI SQL. Now I change Target compatibility to "Same as source 5.08.86"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the double quotes. Either don't quote tables and columns or use backticks (`).

Answer (score 1):

This is your valid sql file :

```
CREATE TABLE `to_import` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `reference` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `trackid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `side_pos1` char(2) character set latin1 NOT NULL,
  `side1` varchar(255) character set latin1 NOT NULL,
  `pos1` char(2) character set latin1 NOT NULL,
  `hh1` char(2) character set latin1 NOT NULL,
  `mm1` char(2) character set latin1 NOT NULL,
  `ss1` char(2) character set latin1 NOT NULL,
  `atl1` varchar(255) character set latin1 NOT NULL,
  `side_pos2` char(2) character set latin1 NOT NULL,
  `side2` varchar(255) character set latin1 NOT NULL,
  `pos2` char(2) character set latin1 NOT NULL,
  `hh2` char(2) character set latin1 NOT NULL,
  `mm2` char(2) character set latin1 NOT NULL,
  `ss2` char(2) character set latin1 NOT NULL,
  `atl2` varchar(255) character set latin1 NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) AUTO_INCREMENT=1311;



#
# Dumping data for table 'to_import'
#

LOCK TABLES `to_import` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `to_import` DISABLE KEYS;*/
REPLACE INTO `to_import` (`id`, `reference`, `trackid`, `side_pos1`, `side1`, `pos1`, `hh1`, `mm1`, `ss1`, `atl1`, `side_pos2`, `side2`, `pos2`, `hh2`, `mm2`, `ss2`, `atl2`, `date`) VALUES
    ('1','0','550','0','Single Side','0','??','??','??','Noizefucker - Tons Of Bluesteel - Special Forces','0','Single Side','0','??','??','??','Noizefucker - Tons Of Bluesteel - Special Forces','2010-06-24 18:54:59');
```

Answer (score 0):

Field names are delimited with backticks, not double quotes.

```
CREATE TABLE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `to_import` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `reference` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
```

etc.